# NSMutableArray objectAtIndex: Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am new to ios development. I am getting certain data from my web services in the form of Dictionary(Which contains a variable and an array of item dictionaries). I am successfully able to store data in userdefaults.

I form a new array named img_urls for a specific key from each item dictionary using for loop.

**My problem is**: when i access this array using [ img_urls objectAtIndex:0] , i get complete array as output rather than getting value only at 0th index. And giving [img_urls objectAtIndex:1] gives me NSRangeException.

Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *restData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Rest data"];
totalResult=[[restData valueForKey:@"totalResult"]intValue];
restaurants=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"], nil ];
for(NSDictionary *item in restaurants)
{


    [img_urls addObject:[item valueForKey:@"profileImage"]];
}
  NSLog(@"REST NAMES%@",[img_urls objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code for creating/assigning `img_urls`.

Comment: addObject statement does so..

Comment: JUST alloc init  your array in view did load .that will work for you.

Comment: @user2885928 No, it does not. That lines add an object to the add. How are you creating the array in the first place?

Comment: That line of code (in the for loop right?) doesn't create anything, it just tries to add an object into `img_urls`.

Comment: Please use `objectForKey` for extracting objects from a dictionary
and not `valueForKey` (used for key value coding).

Comment: seems like you did not call `img_urls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` or `img_urls = [NSMutableArray array]` somewhere before your code.

Comment: img_urls=[[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];

did this already , before adding object

Comment: make sure the classes you are getting is indeed an array, and also the array could be empty... trying to access the first element (0) of an empty array still throws a NSRangeException, [[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"] class] to get the class type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method like this below:-

`[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"], nil ]`to

//Modified below

`[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"]]`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Did you have analyzed an array, Try like this below:-

```
img_urls=[NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *restData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Rest data"];
totalResult=[[restData valueForKey:@"totalResult"]intValue];
restaurants=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"], nil ];
for(NSDictionary *item in restaurants)
{


    [img_urls addObject:[item valueForKey:@"profileImage"]];
}
//Check first array count
if ([img_urls count] > 0)
{
  NSLog(@"REST NAMES%@",[img_urls objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving array([restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"]) as a object to restaurants array while initializing so you will get the whole array when getting by using `objectAtIndex:0`

```
NSDictionary *restData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Rest data"];
totalResult=[[restData valueForKey:@"totalResult"]intValue];
restaurants=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[restData valueForKey:@"restaurants"]];
for(NSDictionary *item in restaurants)
{


    [img_urls addObject:[item valueForKey:@"profileImage"]];
}
  NSLog(@"REST NAMES%@",[img_urls objectAtIndex:0]);
```